# How to insert the content of a file into another file between two matching lines?

Tags: text-processing

I have an xml file process.xml and I want to insert the content of tmp.xml into it. But the caveat is, I need those contents to be inserted between two matching patterns. Here is a snippet of the process.xml file

```
$cat process.xml
...
<fork name="data">
      <path start="process_x" />
      <path start="process_y" />
      <path start="process_z" />
</fork>
...
...
<action name="process_x" />
....
....
</action>
<action name="process_z" />
....
....
</action>
```

And here is the content of tmp.xml file

```
$ cat tmp.xml
<path start="process_a" />
<path start="process_b" />
```

My matching pattern will be "`process_z`" and "`</fork>`" and the content should be pasted between these patterns. 
Here is what I tried..

```
string=$(tac process.xml | grep -m1 -oP '(?<=path start="process_).*(?=" />)')
search="process_$string"
sed -e "/$search/ r tmp.xml" "process.xml"
```

But it inserts the `tmp.xml` content inside the `fork` and `action`. However I need it only inside the `fork` like this.

```
...
<fork name="data">
      <path start="process_x" />
      <path start="process_y" />
      <path start="process_z" />
      <path start="process_a" />
      <path start="process_b" />
</fork>
...
...
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you want to insert the content of that file after the last occurrence of `<path start="process_`. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to insert the content of that file after the last occurrence of `<path start="process_`.

You could do:

```
awk '
  /path start="process_/ {print saved $0; saved=""; n++; next}
  n {saved = saved $0 RS; next}
  {print}
  END{system("cat tmp.xml"); printf "%s", saved}' process.xml
```

Though that would mean storing the part of the file from the last occurrence of `path start="process_` to the end in memory.

Or you could slurp the whole files in memory with:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/.*path start="process_.*?\n\K/<STDIN>/se
               ' process.xml < tmp.xml
```

A variant that checks for the `</fork>` on the next non-empty line:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{.*path start="process_[^\n]*\n\K(?=\s*</fork>)}{<STDIN>}se
               ' process.xml < tmp.xml
```

A variant that aligns the indentation and adds an extra newline character if missing in `tmp.xml`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{(?s:.*)(^\h*).*path start="process_.*\n\K(?=\s*</fork>)}{
 $insert = <STDIN>;
 $indent = $1;
 $insert =~ s/^/$indent/gm;
 $insert =~ s/\n?$/\n/;
 $insert}me' process.xml < tmp.xml
```

With  `-0777 -pe 'code' file`, `perl` runs the `code`, with `$_` being the content of the `file` and prints that `$_` (here modified by the `code`) afterwards.

In there, we have just one substitution command `s{pattern}{replacement}flags`.

The trick to get the last occurrence of the pattern in all those commands is the leading greedy `.*` (here under the `s` flag so it also matches newline characters). As it's greedy, it will try and match as many characters until `^` (a beginning of line with the `m` flag) followed with a sequence of horizontal blanks (`\h*`), which we capture in `$1` with `(\h*)` followed by our pattern followed by the rest of the line (`.*` this time without the `s` flag so won't gobble newline characters) followed by a newline.

After which we add a `\K` to tell `perl` that's the start of the matched text. Then we have a look ahead operator to verify that that newline is followed by a sequence of whitespace (`\s*`) and `</fork>`.

In the replacement, we slurp the content of `tmp.xml` from stdin and insert the captured indentation at the start of each of its lines, add the trailing newline if missing and offer that as the replacement.

---

An alternative could be to process the file twice. Once to retrieve the line number of the last occurrence of the pattern, and the second to insert the file there:

```
sed "$(awk '/path start="process_/{n=NR};END{print n}' < process.xml  
      )r tmp.xml" process.xml
```

Alternatively, maybe you can just insert it before `</fork>`:

```
awk '/<\/fork>/{system("cat tmp.xml")};1' < process.xml
```

Comment: This is fine but is there a way that I can validate both match and then insert between them? What I mean is, I need to check the second pattern `</fork>` as well. Is that possible?

Comment: @Alex, does that `</fork>` have to be on the next line or anywhere further down the file, or anywhere further down the file provided there's no other closing tag in between?

Comment: it is has to be on the next line. Also the inserted content of the tmp.xml file is not intended with that of process.xml and `</fork> appears in the same line of the end of the copied content.

Comment: @Alex, see edit for a perl variant that looks for `</fork>` on the next non-empty line.

Comment: @Alex, see edit which hopefully addresses those extra requirements.

Comment: perl looks perfect to me. If you could edit the answer with a brief explanation on what it does, that would be great. Thanks for all your effort.

Comment: @Alex, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's only one `<fork>` in your file...

Add `</fork>` to the end of your insert string.

Replace `</fork>` with your modified insert string.

Update:  Since the action tags also contain the same process name, expand the 'search' string so that it finds the whole tag `<path start="process_$string" />`.  Or enough of it to eliminate the 'action' matches, like so:  `t="process_$string"`